# LibGDX - Only half of the screen is active playground

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I write a simple snake game using libgdx. Snake is starting to hide on the half of the screen.[image: screen of play ground]. How to change height of the playground? What can cause this issue?

It seems like camera is not fullscreen as should be.

GamePlay screen

```
 public class GamePlay implements Screen {
        private Game game;
        private Stage stage;
        private GameState gameState = new GameState();
        private Viewport viewport;
        int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        private OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    
    
        public GamePlay(Game aGame) {
            game = aGame;
            stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
            camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
            viewport = new FitViewport(width, height, camera);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
            viewport.apply();
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public void show() {
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void render(float delta) {
            camera.update();
            viewport.apply();
    
            gameState.update(delta, viewport);
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gameState.draw(width, height, camera);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height) {
            viewport.update(width, height);
        }
    }
```

GameState

```
public class GameState {

    private int playgroundSize = 30; //How many squares in the board
    private int yOffset = 0; //How high the board is off the bottom
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    private Buttons buttons = new Buttons();
    private Queue<SnakeBody> snakeBody = new Queue<>();
    private float timer = 0;
    private Candy candy = new Candy(playgroundSize);
    private int snakeSize = 10;
    private float colourCounter = 0;

    public GameState() {
        snakeBody.addLast(new SnakeBody(15, 15, playgroundSize)); //head
        snakeBody.addLast(new SnakeBody(15, 14, playgroundSize));
        snakeBody.addLast(new SnakeBody(15, 13, playgroundSize));
    }

    public void update(float delta, Viewport viewport) { //update game logic
        timer += delta;
        colourCounter += delta;
        buttons.update(viewport);
        if (timer > 0.13f) {
            timer = 0;
            advance();
        }
    }

    private void advance() {
        int headX = snakeBody.first().getX();
        int headY = snakeBody.first().getY();
        switch (buttons.getDirection()) {
            //up
            case 1: //right
                snakeBody.addFirst(new SnakeBody(headX + 1, headY, playgroundSize));
                break;
            case 2: //down
                snakeBody.addFirst(new SnakeBody(headX, headY - 1, playgroundSize));
                break;
            case 3: //left
                snakeBody.addFirst(new SnakeBody(headX - 1, headY, playgroundSize));
                break;
            default://should never happen
                snakeBody.addFirst(new SnakeBody(headX, headY + 1, playgroundSize));
                break;
        }
        if (snakeBody.first().getX() == candy.getX() && snakeBody.first().getY() == candy.getY()) {
            snakeSize++;
            candy.randomed(playgroundSize);
        }


        for (int i = 1; i < snakeBody.size; i++) {
            if (snakeBody.get(i).getX() == snakeBody.first().getX()
                    && snakeBody.get(i).getY() == snakeBody.first().getY()) {
                snakeSize = 3;
            }
        }

        while (snakeBody.size - 1 >= snakeSize) {
            snakeBody.removeLast();
        }


    }


    public void draw(float width, int height, OrthographicCamera camera) { //draw snake and board
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.PURPLE);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, width, height);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.FOREST);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(MathUtils.sin(colourCounter), -MathUtils.sin(colourCounter), 1, 1);


        float scaleSnake = width / playgroundSize;
        shapeRenderer.rect(candy.getX() * scaleSnake, candy.getY() * scaleSnake, scaleSnake, scaleSnake);

        for (SnakeBody snBody : snakeBody) {
            shapeRenderer.rect(snBody.getX() * scaleSnake, snBody.getY() * scaleSnake, scaleSnake, scaleSnake);
        }

        shapeRenderer.end();
    }

}
```

I checked i dont't use height/2 anywhere in this project, I don't understand how to resize it, please help!

Comment: Your playground is 30 (30x30) squares, try making the number of squares scale with the size of the display so you have more squares vertically than horizontally.

Comment: I find the solution. I start to redraw the snake on the half of the playground height. Thank you!